# Calling a function on an element inserted into the DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have no control over when and how this element is added to the DOM. But when it does get added I would like to call a call a jQuery function on it. I am looking to match `form[data-validate]` elements then call a jQuery function I wrote: `validate`

A temporary solution I have come up with:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMNodeInserted', function(event) {
  if (event.target.nodeName === 'FORM' && $(event.target).data('validate')) {
    return $(event.target).validate();
  }
}, false);
```

According to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Mutation_events this code will "profoundly degrades the performance of further DOM modifications to that document (making them 1.5 - 7 times slower!)" and the browser compatibility is rather poor.

Can anybody do better?

Comment: I think it might be a cue for you to rethink your design. Maybe...

Comment: could you elaborate on what you mean by " no control over when and how this element is added to the DOM" ?

Comment: How is this element being added?

Comment: My Rails gem `client_side_validations` calls $('form[data-validate]').validate() on page load. The problem I'm starting to see is with people loading pages via AJAX.

Comment: I don't think it's your job to handle these cases. If the user wants to load new forms via AJAX, shouldn't they just call `.validate()` on the loaded content?

Comment: Yeah, I think you are correct. I was looking for some validation on that. Thank you.

Comment: Instead of going this route, why not just look at the specific ajax request that gets this form? Maybe you could add your events there?

Answer (score 0):

Try delegating the event..

```
$(document).on('DOMNodeInserted' , 'form' , function(event){
    if (event.target.nodeName === 'FORM' && $(event.target).data('validate')) {
       return $(event.target).validate();
    }
     return false;
});
```

This will make sure that the function will be called when a new form is created...

Comment: You can get rid of the `if` condition and replace `form` with `form[data-validate]`.

Comment: Why is this any better?  Still has performance issues.  Still has browser compatibility issues.  Still is deprecated by Mozilla.